# "cannot connect to the docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. is the docker daemon running?"

Tags: mysql, docker

When I execute the command 'docker pull mysql', I'm encountering the message below.

`cannot connect to the docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. is the docker daemon running?`

How can I resolve this issue?

I've expecting to run mysql on docker.

Comment: You need to add your user to docker group. sudo usermod -aG docker {username}